# How to keep original video file header in FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, codec, video-encoding

I'm trying to use FFMpeg to do some processing on my input video files which is then given to an emulator software (a packetization software) for further processing. The emulator is basically a packetization software. But no matter what it is, the original video file which works is attached. The creator of the file said he used `bento4` tool for creation of the file. What is different from that tool from FFmpeg?

The problem is that the emulator can read the original video file, but when I simply use the command `ffmpeg -i input.video -c copy output.mp4`, while it should essentially copy all configurations, the emulator can not read and process the new file.

[Here is a copy of the original `.mp4`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yds8wcrp2qqd7a7/edv_g24.mp4?dl=0) file which works fine in the emulator.

I used `mediainfo` tool to compare the details of the two files and noticed while all video codec related configs are the same, there are some differences in the header sizes which probably are causing the problems. Is there any ways to force FFmpeg to keep headers information (aside from codecs)? Or maybe there are other problems? In any case, the output video is not being totally the same.

**UPDATE:**
I'm still struggling with the issue. I looked into the emulator code, and it parses the `MOOV` and fragment headers for information. Using the MP4 explorer software, I notice in my generated `.mp4` file, for all `moof.traf.trun`, sample duration is 0, but in the Track Fragment Header box, it sets the `default_sample_duration` to 512. While in the working file, there is no `default_sample_duration`, and each individual sample has a duration of size 512. I guess this might be the problem. Now any ways to make it like original?

[image]

Comment: The emulator is basically a packetization software. But no matter what it is, the original video file which works is attached.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be solved … at least not without having access to that “emulator” software and debugging it. Do you get any log output as to what's wrong? Does it say why it cannot process the file? Can you check with a developer?

Comment: Not a specific error. It looks NULL to it: `loading binary file\ pthread_join(thread[1], NULL);`

Comment: Hm, this question comes down to guesswork then. It's ultimately a bug/problem in proprietary software, which we cannot (easily) solve without a lot of back and forward.

Comment: UPDATE: The creator of the file said he used bento4 tool for creation of the file. What is different from that tool from FFMPEG?

Answer (score 1):

If by header, you mean the MOOV box/atom, then ffmpeg will always construct a new box. It cannot copy boxes or their contents over. What your command does is tell FFmpeg to demux all streams from the original file and remux them into a new container.

Can you be specific in what your emulator looks for?

Comment: The emulator is basically a packetization software. But no matter what it is, the original video file which works is attached.

Comment: Your attached file has MOOV upfront, which ffmpeg does not do, by default. Try `ffmpeg -i input.video -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Comment: Once we know if that's the issue. The header aspect is a guess by the OP.

Comment: @Mulvya that didn't work.

Comment: ok, mp4box indicates your source is fragmented mp4. So, try `ffmpeg -i input.video -c copy -movflags +dash output.mp4`

Comment: @Mulvya Yes it is for streaming purposes. That throws a segmentation fault! `segmentation fault (core dumped)` Looks like we are getting close!

Comment: UPDATE: The creator of the file said he used bento4 tool for creation of the file. What is different from that tool from FFMPEG?

Comment: It's a weird software you're using that crashes upon getting an unrecognized file. Can you share any details? Alternatively, try `ffmpeg -i input.video -c copy -movflags +dash+global_sidx -brand isom output.mp4` but this is guesswork.

Comment: @Ariana When you do `ffmpeg -i edv_g24.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart -brand isom edv_g24_2.mp4`, the [resulting file](https://pastebin.com/raw/SKKWdn5J) is not that different from [the original](https://pastebin.com/raw/zqEwjipF) – this is using `mp4info` from `bento4`. The only difference there is the major brand list and track flags. But if that crashes your software, you have to fix that obviously. I'm sure a developer can investigate that segfault based on the converted file.

Comment: No chance. The null error again. Thanks anyways. I should talk to the developers probably