# How to use trim and concat of FFmpeg correctly?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, windows-11

I'm using the [media-autobuild_suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite) (on Windows 11). My installation is a week old. Tomorrow I will update it again.

I have one private video file. I wish to cut out two parts of it and then merge the two parts into a single result video file. I also wish to re-encode the video stream with `-c:v libx265 -crf xx -preset veryslow`, see [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) and the audio stream with `-c:a libfdk_aac -b:a xxxk`, see [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC). In addition I wish to delete all meta data in the result video file with `-map_metadata -1 -metadata title="" -map_chapters -1 -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact`, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg). I wish to do my task in one run of `FFmpeg`, so I decided to use `trim` and `concat`, see [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#filter).

To demonstrate what I have done so far, I'm using a public [test video](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4) from [here](https://gist.github.com/jsturgis/3b19447b304616f18657).

For my case I adapted the solution from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1229945/ffmpeg-split-video-and-merge-back). I done multiple test cases:

Case 1 (two source files, include meta data editing and full time stamps, for example `00.000:16.820`):

`ffmpeg -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="" -map_chapters -1 -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=00.000:16.820,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [0:a]atrim=00.000:16.820,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; [1:v]trim=153.000:348.840,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [1:a]atrim=153.000:348.840,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -preset veryslow -map "[a]" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k result/"BigBuckBunny".mkv`.

Case 2 (only one source file, include meta data editing and short time stamps, for example `0:16.820`):

`ffmpeg -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="" -map_chapters -1 -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:16.820,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [0:a]atrim=0:16.820,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; [0:v]trim=153:348.840,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [0:a]atrim=153:348.840,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -preset veryslow -map "[a]" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k result/"BigBuckBunny".mkv`.

Case 3 (two source files, include meta data editing and short time stamps, see case 2):

`ffmpeg -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -metadata title="" -map_chapters -1 -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:16.820,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [0:a]atrim=0:16.820,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; [1:v]trim=153:348.840,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [1:a]atrim=153:348.840,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -preset veryslow -map "[a]" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k result/"BigBuckBunny".mkv`.

Case 4 (two source files, without meta data editing and short time stamps, see case 2):

`ffmpeg -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:16.820,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [0:a]atrim=0:16.820,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; [1:v]trim=153:348.840,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [1:a]atrim=153:348.840,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -preset veryslow -map "[a]" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k result/"BigBuckBunny".mkv`.

Case 5 (only one source file, without meta data editing and short time stamps, see case 2):

`ffmpeg -i source/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:16.820,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [0:a]atrim=0:16.820,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; [1:v]trim=153:348.840,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [1:a]atrim=153:348.840,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -preset veryslow -map "[a]" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k result/"BigBuckBunny".mkv`.

The result of all five cases is always the same (except for the meta data). I get a result video file with a duration of 16.820 s, which means that only the first part from 0 s to 16.820 s is processed. **If needed**, I can provide for each case the output from the command line.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. The duration of the output file is 3 min 32 sec. The fact that you are using `libfdk_aac` implies that you are using non-standard build of FFmpeg. Try the same command with the latest stable release from [here](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds) (download `ffmpeg-release-full.7z`).

Comment: Hello @Rotem! Thank you for your comment! Yes the reason was actual the non-standard build of `FFmpeg`. By the way: Several month ago I was able to do the task with this non-standard build of `FFmpeg`, but after one update it wasn't possible any more.